# Jmeter Authentication eror

Tags: jmeter

I am getting the below error in jmeter, how to resolve this.

> WARN o.a.h.c.p.RequestTargetAuthentication: NEGOTIATE authentication
>   error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid
>   credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos
>   tgt))

Steps I followed :

I am using Http authorization manager and provided all details like Base URL, user, password, domain, Mechanism (BASIC) , I have parameterized the test with different users login using HTTP auth manager.

My application used NTLM authentication, my test is running successful but I am getting above warning in log file.

How to resolve this ?

Comment: it seems you don't have valid kerberos ticket. Something is not configured properly. Can you post your debug logs  please ?

Comment: Please find debug logs here , https://pastebin.com/K0iYkArk